# How to modify Publish Artifact folder $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) prior its zip creation in VSTS Build process?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

I defined VSTS build process till Publish Artifact steps. By default, VSTS agent creates 5 files in Publish Artifact location (c:\vsts-agent_work\1\a) including important build file i.e zip folder. When I checked zip folder, I found long path where my build files are located. folder path in zip -

> \Content\C_C\vsts-agent\_work\1\s\ABCProject\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp

I got to know that source of zip file is source directory after looking in _work folder-

> C:\vsts-agent\_work\1\s\ABCProject\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp

I wanted one folder (RDLCReports Folder) in C:\vsts-agent\_work\1\s\CCM2015MVC\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp directory. I managed to create that folder using copy files task. I did this step before Publish Artifact step.

Problem is when Publish Artifact step is completed, I didn't get that folder in zip file.

below is snapshot of VSTS build process-

[image]

below is Publish Artifact location -

[image]

Please let me know how can add that folder in zip? and I also want to know which source path VSTS build has considered to make it as zip folder?

Comment: If you want files in a webdeploy package, add them to the project as content with `CopyToPublishDirectory` set to `true` in the MSBuild file.

Comment: Hi @SSD Did you tried out below solution, how did it go? please let me know if there is any question?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT I referred your unzip and zip approach and seems to be correct but didn't try. What I did is - I copied RDLC Reports Folder in $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) location using Copy Files Task before Publish Artifact task so now I have both zip package and Folder. In Release section (deployment process), I added FTP upload task (for RDLC report folder) after Azure App Service Deploy and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents in folder (c:\vsts-agent_work\1\a) is created at the **Visual Studio Build task** step. So that even if you managed to create RDLCReports folder in `C:\vsts-agent\_work\1\s\CCM2015MVC\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp` using copy file task. It will not be copied and zipped to `c:\vsts-agent_work\1\a` again.

There is a workaround to achieve this. If you want to keep the folder structure in the zip file, You can follow below steps:

1,You need to add a **Extract file task** to extract the zip file in folder $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) to a different folder (eg.$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/Temp)
[image]

2, Add the **copy file task** to create RDLCReports folder inside the extracted folder in $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/Temp
[image]

3,  Add a **Archive files task** to archive the files in the folder 
 $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/Temp where folder RDLCReports is created.

[image]

Make sure **uncheck** option **Prepend root folder name to archive paths** and **check** **Replace existing archive**

(For above example. My test project is named AboutSite and the zip file is AboutSite.zip.  And the folder structure is `Content\C_C\agent\_work\1\s\AboutSite\AboutSite\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\PubTmp\Out`. You need to make a little change to the paths and file name according to your project.)

For your project you may find  the contents in `C:\vsts-agent\_work\1\s\ABCProject\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp` is the same with your zip file. So there is an another workaround is to add copy file task and target this path `C:\vsts-agent\_work\1\s\ABCProject\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp` . And then add the archive file  task to archive this folder. However this workaround cannot keep the origin file structure.